# Using Java in Google App Engine, how do I make a BMP image from an array of arrays of int r, g, b values?

Tags: java, image, google-app-engine, bmp

What I have is: for each of the colors r, g and b, a two-dimensional array of integers in the [0,255] range. What I want is: create a BMP out of this array and send it to the client. The problem is, I cannot use java.awt.Color, BufferedImage, etc., since these are off-limits in the App Engine. The App Engine does offer an image manipulation service which, however, is meant for images I already have, not for creating images from scratch.

I am considering teaching myself how to 'manually' create a BMP, but this does seem like a lot of work. Should I do this, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [BMP format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) is pretty simple compared to JPG or PNG for example.

It has lots of header fields and bits, but you don't need to calculate/fill all. Basically what you need to do is create/write the BMP header which is less than 100 bytes (~56 if I remember well). Only a few fields you need to set, e.g. image size in pixels, image type (e.g. bits/bytes per pixel) etc. You can use the image type which is identical to yours: 3 bytes per pixel (r, g and b components).

Once you have this, the image data follows which you can just write as you have, one thing to keep in mind is that BMP stores images upside-down, and it may have line padding to be a multiple of 4 bytes for example.

That's all! Note that I haven't mentioned `java.awt.Image` or `java.awt.Color` because they are not needed to create simple BMPs.

I consider posting full code out of "scope" as you haven't posted any.

Here's an example Java implementation, use it or modify/tweak it to your needs:

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077561/learn-java/java-tip-60--saving-bitmap-files-in-java.html

There are also many other Java implementations, don't be afraid to search.

Comment: I use a very similar approach for generating PNGs on App Engine, inspired by [this example](https://github.com/greghaskins/googleappengine/tree/master/java/demos/mandelbrot/src/com/google/appengine/demos/mandelbrot)